# NSInvalidArgument Exception when click next Button in Walkthrough Screens

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipageviewcontroller

I am making IntroScreens for iOS app, Every thing is perfect but when I click next button it shows NSInvalidArgumentException error

**pageContentViewController**

```
- (IBAction)nextButtonTapped:(id)sender {

switch (self.pageIndex) {
    case 0:
    case 1:
        pageViewController  = ((PageViewController *)self.parentViewController);
        [pageViewController forward:self.pageIndex];
        break;
    case 2:

       [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"LoginScreen" sender:nil];

        break;

    default:
        break;
}
}
```

**PageViewController**

```
-(void)forward:(NSUInteger)index{

    [self.pageViewController  setViewControllers:@[[self viewControllerAtIndexArabic:index +1]] direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:YES completion:nil];


  }

reason: '-[UIPageViewController forward:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fb2cf009600
```

Comment: It's crashing because `self.parentViewController` is not an instance of `PageViewController` it's an instance of `UIPageViewController`

Comment: then what should I do it here

Answer (score 0):

The issue it with the following code block
 `pageViewController  = ((PageViewController *)self.parentViewController);`

I guess you have set your pageviewcontroller in storyboard which is an instance of UIPageViewController but in the code you are trying to access PageViewController ( which I guess is a third party controller ).

So you must change the class of your UIPageViewController in storyboard to PageViewController.

Comment: PageViewController is class where pageViewcontroller is instance of UIPageViewController which I declare in PageViewController.h

Comment: Yes, I understand that but on runtime pageViewcontroller is instance of UIPageViewController which doesn't have forward: method.

Comment: so how I called the forward method of PageContenViewController from PageViewController class then